# Does Twitter bootstrap buttons works on iPad?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Twitter provides these [nice looking buttons](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons) which can be used in place of radio/checkbox.

[image: Bootstrap buttons]

Does any has used them in production? If yes, then how well do they work? Specially, I want to know if these buttons work on iPad.

Comment: They are working... If you wish to learn more about touch events - here is a short post I've wrote: http://greenido.wordpress.com/2011/06/21/html5-on-mobile/

Comment: DID YOU TRY IT? Seems like a logical step to answer your question.

Comment: @epascarello I don't have an iPad. Hence testing is bit difficult

Comment: download Xcode from Apple App Store, which includes iPhone/iPod/iPad simulator. It's free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, definitely. If you look at their [Bootstrap, from Twitter Home Page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) you can see

> **Cross-everything**
>
> Originally built with only modern browsers
> in mind, Bootstrap has evolved to include support for all major
> browsers (even IE7!) and, with Bootstrap 2, tablets and smartphones,
> too.

Also there is ipadzip.com which is powered on nodejs and bootstrap as an example.